# How do I run a Python program in the Vim editor without closing it?

Tags: python, vim

I found the answer to my question last night: *How do I run the simple Hello world in python in the Vim editor without closing Vim?* but I cannot find it today. It was real simple, something like `:!python helloworld.py` to do but everything I try today does not work and my searches in Google do not turn up the same as I got last night.

Comment: It is `:!python filename.py`, from the directory. Can you add the exact commands you tried?

Comment: I was using that command.  The  difference, I figured, is today I was in a Ubuntu terminal in termux.  I got out of the Ubuntu terminal and back to termux and the command  worked?? The Ubuntu terminal in termux is something new to me. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

In vim you can run commmands inside the editor using the `:!` terminology.
So for example, a normal python script would be executed using:

```
python script_name.py
```

From inside vim you can run it by doing the following:

```
:!python script.name.py
```

Hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of Vim substituting `%` in the command line with the current buffer's file name (see [`:help c_%`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_%25)) and do just

```
:!python %
```

I find myself running `:!./%` quite a lot when writing any kind of interpreted language.

This uses `:!` to run the following stuff in the shell. The command to run is `./%` which is `./` for the current directory `%` is the file name as we know.

There are three preconditions:

- Vim's working directory needs to be where the file resides
- the file has the *executable* property set (`:!chmod +x %` to set it without leaving Vim)
- the file has a shebang that points to the interpreter, e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env python` as its first line